# Bitbucket won't run my hook after merge

Tags: git, merge, hook, bitbucket

It's quite strange to see, but when I commit to master - my bitbucket Jenkins hook works like a charm. But if I perform

```
git checkout _testing
git merge master
git push
```

it seems that hook is not going to trigger at all.
Is there a way to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a piece of functionality not currently available on bitbucket, which sucks for doing Continuous Integration :(

See: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7775/post-service-does-not-provide-useful

61 people asked for it to be fixed, but bitbucket does not seem to care much.

Comment: The fact that this still hasn't been fixed is... I have no words.
https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/7775/post-service-does-not-provide-useful#comment-16154855